# qr code shows up immediatly before i click the button reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-qr-code

im using react-qr-code package for generating qr code but the problem is it renders immediately instead of after clicking the submit button
so for that, i want a function that can render the qr code after clicking the button
i don't know what a should do i try slit it to components but still the same

```
import React from 'react';
import './QrCodeInfo.css';
import QRCode from "react-qr-code";

import { useState } from 'react';

function QrCodeInfo(props) {
   


  const [wifiName, setWifiName] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(''); 

const clickButton=()=>{
    let qrimage = password
    return (qrimage)
}


    return(
<div className='center'>
<div className=" center card shadow">
<div className='flex'>
<form>
    <div className="user-details">

              <div className="input-box">
                <span className="details">WifiName</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your WifiName"  value={wifiName}
                   onChange={event => setWifiName(event.target.value)} required/>
              </div>
              <div className="input-box">
                <span className="details">Password</span>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Password" value={password}
                    onChange={event => setPassword(event.target.value)} required/>
              </div>
              </div>
              <div className='center'>
              <button type='button'className='center' onClick={clickButton}> Submit
               </button>
               </div>
</form>
<div>

<h1 >{wifiName}</h1>
<QRCode value='' />
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>





        )

}

export default QrCodeInfo;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you just render the `QRCode` component without any condition. You can try this when the password has value and the user click the button. Show the QR code.

```
import React from "react";
import QRCode from "react-qr-code";

import { useState } from "react";

function QrCodeInfo() {
  const [wifiName, setWifiName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [qrCodeVisible, setQrCodeVisible] = useState(false);

  const clickButton = () => {
    let qrimage = password;
    setQrCodeVisible(!!qrimage);
  };

  return (
    <div className="center">
      <div className=" center card shadow">
        <div className="flex">
          <form>
            <div className="user-details">
              <div className="input-box">
                <span className="details">WifiName</span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter your WifiName"
                  value={wifiName}
                  onChange={(event) => setWifiName(event.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-box">
                <span className="details">Password</span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter your Password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="center">
              <button type="button" className="center" onClick={clickButton}>
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <div>
            <h1>{wifiName}</h1>
            {qrCodeVisible && <QRCode value={password} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default QrCodeInfo;
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-71699315-2itv5f)